# Bootstrap/Jquery accordion not working propertly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a simple accordion in JSfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Rnpb2/) and it works just fine. However when I try to replicate the result on my site, it just isn't working. Pressing on the elements just adds #first, #second and #third at the end of the URL. Probably because I am a rookie the problem is easily solvable but I cannot find it. Here is the whole code of my page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css"/>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/fabric.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="page">
    <header class="container">
        <div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav"><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                <li class="nav"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav" ><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>




    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="panel-title">
                            <a href="#first"
                               data-toggle="collapse"
                               data-parent="#accordion">Shape</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="first">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> First <p/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="panel-title">
                                <a href="#second"
                                   data-toggle="collapse"
                                   data-parent="#accordion">Shape</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="second">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> Second <p/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="panel-title">
                                <a href="#third"
                                   data-toggle="collapse"
                                   data-parent="#accordion">Shape</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="third">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> Third <p/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4">

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

I have added so many different sources in an attempt to make it work, but to no avail. I was adding them one by one.

Comment: Could you please add your site also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load jquery before you load bootstrap. If you look at your console you might see an error. Also you should place your scripts at the bottom of you html so that your scripts don't block the UI from loading.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="page">
    <header class="container">
        <div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav"><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                <li class="nav"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav" ><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>




    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="panel-title">
                            <a href="#first"
                               data-toggle="collapse"
                               data-parent="#accordion">Shape</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="first">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> First <p/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="panel-title">
                                <a href="#second"
                                   data-toggle="collapse"
                                   data-parent="#accordion">Shape</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="second">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> Second <p/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="panel-title">
                                <a href="#third"
                                   data-toggle="collapse"
                                   data-parent="#accordion">Shape</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="third">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p> Third <p/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4">

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/fabric.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the jsfiddle you posted, if you inspect the results you'll see that bootstrap is loaded after jquery.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        @import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
        .panel-heading {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
        $(window).load(function(){

        });//]]>
    </script>

</head>
```

Comment: I knew it was that easy and I was just doing newbie mistakes. Thank you very much.